# Adding touch event listeners to MapView

Tags: android

So I want to return the the geo location of whatever point I touch on the map,but my code just doesn't do anything on moving across/clicking the screen. I'm new to Java as well as Android, so I think its something to do with my lack of knowledge of coding in java. Here's my code

```
package sdpd.loc;

import sdpd.loc.createNote.mapOverlay;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class createNote extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}       

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStates){       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStates);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    MapView mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.MapView);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


}   


class mapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{
    @Override

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapview){

        if (event.getAction()==1){
            GeoPoint p=mapview.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

How  do I get it to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't register your custom Overlay class `mapOverlay` (btw. class names start always with an uppercase letter in Java) to the MapView. Do this by creating an instance of the class and adding it to the overlays collection of you MapView.

You can do this by appending following code to the onResume() method of your activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStates){       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStates);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    MapView mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.MapView);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlay myOverlay = new mapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> overlays = mMapView.getOverlays();        
    overlays.add(myOverlay);
}
```

Now your overlay is registered and the touch events should be processed.

Comment: Thanks!I'm new to Java, so I keep slipping up.